# Method not found using trait

Tags: rust

I'm a beginner of Rust. I created an trait named `Floating`, `f32` and `f64` implement this trait. A generic struct `Vec` requiring that `T` must implement  `Floating` trait. I would like to compute `norm` of the vector, this won't compile with the error message said that **no method named `sqrt` found for type parameter `T` in the current scope**. Why this is happening and how would it work?

```rust
use std::ops::{Mul, Add};

trait Floating: Sized + Copy + Clone + Mul<Output=Self> + Add<Output=Self> {}

impl Floating for f32 {}

impl Floating for f64 {}

struct Vec<T: Floating> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
    z: T,
}

impl<T: Floating> Vec<T> {
    fn norm(&self) -> T {
        (self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y + self.z * self.z).sqrt()
    }
}


fn main() {
    let v: Vec<f32> = Vec {x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0};
    println!("norm is {:?}", v.norm());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you probably shouldn't name your type `Vec`, to avoid conflicts and confusion with the [`std::vec::Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) container.

---

The issue is that (your) `Vec` only knows that `T` requires `Floating`, and `Floating` doesn't have a `sqrt` method. So you need to define that yourself.

```rust
trait Floating: Sized + Copy + Clone + Mul<Output = Self> + Add<Output = Self> {
    fn sqrt(self) -> Self;
}

impl Floating for f32 {
    fn sqrt(self) -> Self {
        f32::sqrt(self)
    }
}

impl Floating for f64 {
    fn sqrt(self) -> Self {
        f64::sqrt(self)
    }
}
```

This is where the [`num` crate](https://crates.io/crates/num) comes in handy, as it defines a [`Float` trait](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/trait.Float.html), which includes among others a [`sqrt()`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/trait.Float.html#tymethod.sqrt) method. Using `num` you can simplify your example to:

```rust
// num = "0.3"
use num::Float;

struct Vec<T: Float> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
    z: T,
}

impl<T: Float> Vec<T> {
    fn norm(&self) -> T {
        (self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y + self.z * self.z).sqrt()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<f32> = Vec {
        x: 1.0,
        y: 1.0,
        z: 1.0,
    };
    println!("norm is {:?}", v.norm());
}
```

Comment: The `sqrt` is a method defined over `f32` and `f64`, why it couldn't be found in such case?

Comment: `T` can be anything, so while yes `f32` and `f64` has a `sqrt` method, there's no guarantee from the point-of-view of `T` requiring `Floating` that any `T` has a `sqrt` method, e.g. neither `Vec<i32>` or `Vec<String>` would have a `sqrt` method.

Comment: @vallentin What happens now if one calls `norm()` on a `Vec<i32>`?

Comment: @ruohola Since `Floating`/`Float` is not implemented for `i32`, then in that even you'd receive a compile error in the form of "trait bound not satisfied" from the struct requirement. If you remove the requirement from `struct Vec<T: Float>`, i.e. change it to `struct Vec<T>`. Then you'd receive a "method not found" compile error